# Symfony2 DQL Update query with Many to Many

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql, symfony-2.8, doctrine-query

I have three tables "**category**", "**product**" and "**product_category**".
First two tables are created from two entity Category and Product.
Third table "product_category" is auto generated by framework doctrine console command.

Now I can get (fetch) product relational data (based on category id) from below query, which is fine.

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->leftJoin('p.category', 'c')
                ->select('p')
                ->where('c.id = :category_id')
                ->setParameter('category_id', 2)
                ->getQuery()->getSQL();
```

But how can I use Many-to-Many relation to **Update Data**?
I had Tried with several queries but its not working!!!
( I want to update all product status to inactive (2), whose category status is (2 = Inactive).

Answer (score 0):

When doing a query on a table that has children. You can also just fetch the parent item, and doctrine will automatically handle the child objects. If you have a `getCategory` within the `Product` entity, it will resolve the category automatically.

Probably what you are looking for is cascading of events. of which is explained within [Doctrine 2 ManyToMany cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033825/doctrine-2-manytomany-cascade)