# Doctrine ManyToMany self referencing bidirectionnal - Parent not updated

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, relational-database

I'm trying to create a ManyToMany relation beetwin services of a company.
Each service had **N parents** services and **N children** services.

I looked at the doctrine documentation here : [Many-To-Many, Self-referencing](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing) and I implemented it as followed :

Here is my service entity :

```
<?
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Service
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Service", mappedBy="enfants", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $parents;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Service", inversedBy="parents")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="app_services_hierarchy",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="enfant_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $enfants;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->enfants  = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->parents  = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------Enfants
    public function getEnfants(){
        return $this->enfants;
    }

    public function setEnfants($enfant){
        $this->enfants = $enfant;
    }

    public function addEnfant(Service $s){
        $this->enfants[] = $s;
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEnfant(Service $s){
        $this->enfants->removeElement($s);
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------Parents
    public function getParents(){
        return $this->parents;
    }

    public function setParents($parents){
        $this->parents = $parents;
    }

    public function addParent(Service $s){
        $this->parents[] = $s;
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeParent(Service $s){
        $this->parents->removeElement($s);
    }

}
```

And here is my edit function( Controller.php) :

```
public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $service  = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Service::class)->find($id);
    $form     = $this->createForm(ServiceType::class, $service);
    $form     ->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager ->persist($service);

        dump($service);

        $entityManager ->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Service:edit.html.twig', array(
        'form'      => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

And the generated form looks like :

[image: ServiceType generated]

**PROBLEM :**

My problem is that the **childrens are updated but not the parents**. I can see the parents in the `$service` variable when I `dump()` it in my controler but the only ones updated in my database table (app_services_hierarchie) are the children.

Comment: Have a look there 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033825/doctrine-2-manytomany-cascade

Comment: Could have be this but it's still not working ... The weird part is that when i update, the form is reloaded, the parents I selected before are selected (so my entity is filled with parents) but nothing in database so they disapear as soon as I reload the page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `$parents` and `$enfants` in your code is that the service you are looking at is the **Owning side** in case of your `$enfants` mapping, but not in the case of your `$parents` mapping.

Doctrine will not store the `$parents` unless you tell it to do so via `cascade={"persist"}`.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Service", mappedBy="enfants", cascade={"persist"})
 */
```

This is basically the same anwer given in the post linked by @GregoireDucharme.

**Edit**: after some research, apparently this problem cannot be solved using cascade. According to the [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html):

> Doctrine will only check the owning side of an association for changes.

So what you have to do is tell your `$parents` to also update the `$children` property.

```
public function addParent(Service $s){
    $this->parents[] = $s;
    $s->addEnfant($this);
    return $this;
}

public function removeParent(Service $s){
    $this->parents->removeElement($s);
    $s->removeEnfant($this);
}
```

In your form, make sure to specify the following:

```
->add('parents', 'collection', array(
    'by_reference' => false,
    //...
))
```

(I haven't spellchecked any of the code above, so tread carefully.)

If `'by_reference'` is set to `true`, `addParent` and `removeParent` will not be called.

Credit goes to this [blog post](https://afilina.com/doctrine-not-saving-manytomany) by Anny Filina.

It also states that you can remove the `cascade` option from your `$parents` property, but you probably should add `cascade={"persist","remove"}` to your `$enfants` property.

Comment: I tried this solution before but it is still not working, the entity is updated but not the database. The database is just updated for the children (enfants) / I edited my question to add the cascade persist (even if it is not working, you both told me to add it, I may be a part of the solution, and it makes sens)

Comment: have you tried adding `refresh` as well? `cascade={"persist", "refresh"}`. really not sure if that has anything to do with "updating" entities, but it is worth a try.

Comment: @Gauthier edited my response. looks like the `cascade` option at that position is not the solution you were looking for.

Comment: I think I'm so close, I get the error "Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\Service", "string" given" when I try to update, and the form is not displayed as a choice list anymore. I feel I'm closer. Thanks anyway for looking this, I think you found the problem @micha